# What local-storage tooling does WebSharper provide?

Tags: serialization, f#, local-storage, websharper

In looking at the [documentation for WebSharper's local storage](http://websharper.com/samples/DataStorage), the SetItem item is `string * string -> unit` (and GetItem is `string -> string`).

This means that I'll need to convert anything I want to store into strings and do the reverse to retrieve them. Or, to put it in another way, I'll need to serialize and de-serialize them. Is there a way to use the behind-the-scenes conversion that WebSharper already does for RPC calls, or am I stuck with using a server-side library like [FsPicker](http://nessos.github.io/FsPickler/index.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built in yet, I have been using this helper module to make local storage usable the same way as a ref cell:

```
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper

// Helper for handling localstorage, making a stored value work like a ref cell.
[<JavaScript; AutoOpen>]
module LocalStorage =
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html5

    let localStorage = Window.Self.LocalStorage

    type IValue<'T> = 
        abstract Value: 'T with get, set

    let [<Inline>] ( ! ) (x: IValue<_>) = x.Value
    let [<Inline>] ( := ) (x: IValue<_>) v = x.Value <- v

    // Redefining Ref to use IValue
    type Ref<'T> (value: 'T) =
        let mutable v = value 
        interface IValue<'T> with
            member this.Value
                with get() = v
                and set value = v <- value

    let [<Inline>] ref v = Ref  v
    let incr i = i := !i + 1
    let decr i = i := !i - 1

    type IStorageItem<'T> =
        inherit IValue<'T>
        abstract Save: unit -> unit
        abstract Delete: unit -> unit

    type JSONStorageItem<'T>(key, defaultVal) = 
        let mutable value = None

        let getValue() =
            match value with
            | Some v -> v
            | _ ->
                let v =
                    match localStorage.GetItem key with
                    | null -> defaultVal
                    | s -> 
                        Json.Parse s :?> _
                value <- Some v
                v

        interface IStorageItem<'T> with
            member this.Value
                with get() = getValue()
                and  set v =
                    try localStorage.SetItem(key, Json.Stringify v)  
                        value <- Some v 
                    with _ -> JavaScript.Alert "Saving data to storage failed."

            member this.Save() = 
                try localStorage.SetItem(key, Json.Stringify (getValue()))  
                with _ -> JavaScript.Alert "Saving data to storage failed."

            member this.Delete() =
                localStorage.RemoveItem key
                value <- None

    let [<Inline>] getJSONStorage key defaultVal = JSONStorageItem<_>(key, defaultVal) :> IStorageItem<_>
```

However this can currently only stringify/parse straight data objects: record, list, array, tuple and union types are ok, but no prototypes are restored.

Comment: Ah, it seems that Json.Stringify has the type `Json.Value -> string` and Json.Parse has type `string -> Json.Value`. It looks like I need some kind of translator to serialize/de-serialize my object into a Json.Value. (Or do I need to constrain `'T`?)

Comment: `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Core.Json` contains server-side JSON utilities, `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Json` has the client side ones. Sorry, I forgot to include that, I had `open IntelliFactory.WebSharper` before my snippet but haven't opened `Core`.

Comment: Actually, the module I'm using is `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Core.Json`. Hm. Was there a breaking change or something? I'm using WebSharper v2.5.128.65

Comment: The compiler error I get for the type parameter of `JSONStorageItem<'T>` is `This type parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be 'Json.Value'`. I've confirmed that the fully qualified module for `Json.Parse` is `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Core.Json.Parse`. Hm...

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. `Core` has server-side, .NET utilities for JSON parsing and printing. Do not use this. `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Json` has the client-side functions.

Comment: For usage: create/get storage: `let test = LocalStorage.getJSONStorage "test" ""` (key and default value); save a value: `test := "Testing"`; retrieve a value: `!test`